# .gitignore file in VS2019 doesn't handle Debug folders

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a local .gitignore file in my repo's root folder with the content pasted from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

After I added the content, it ignored some of the checked out files, but they're still more than 200 files left as it can be seen on the screenshot.

[image]

I am using VS 2019.

What might be the problem?

EDIT: After I do `git checkout .`, I get "nothing added to commit" message, and then whenever I build, there are more than 200 modified files.

Comment: The files were already added prior to you adding the `.gitignore`. Try searching.

Comment: No. I start with no checked out files and existing .gitignore and whenever I execute a build the files are checking out.

Comment: _"I start with no checked out files"_ - that's TFS terminology. You're not on TFS, you're on Git. You have a branch checked out, and that branch already tracks files that you now want ignored. Do a `git status` from the command line and you'll see. The fact that those files are listed under "changes" proves that they are currently being tracked by Git.

Comment: Sorry for my TFS dialect. After I do `git checkout .`, I get `nothing added to commit`, and then whenever I build, there are more than 200 modified files. Can't put it clearer than that.

Comment: _"there are more than 200 modified files"_ - that is **because they were already added to source control before you added the `.gitignore` file**. See duplicate linked above to remove them from source control.

Comment: Yes. This resolves it. Sorry for my ignorance. I read the thread you pointed, but never realized this was my problem.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.